# Random selection of values from a table with conditions

Tags: r

I need help with randomly selecting different pairs of values from a table because I want to add an extra condition.

The condition is that exactly one pair of values from each number should always be selected (there are 7 different numbers in total). So in the end I want to have 7 new values.

Thank you very much for the help.

```
table <- read.table("table_all_values.txt", dec = ".", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
x=show(table)


rows <- sample(1:nrow(table), 7, TRUE)
new_table <- table[rows,]
head(new_table, 7)
```

| number | y | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7.180555 | 2.340444 |
| 1 | 7.181284 | 2.338456 |
| 1 | 7.176718 | 2.32838 |
| 1 | 7.166039 | 2.311754 |
| 1 | 7.115937 | 2.260071 |
| 1 | 7.115112 | 2.252853 |
| 1 | 6.787013 | 1.880814 |
| 1 | 6.787013 | 1.875061 |
| 1 | 6.832446 | 1.973128 |
| 1 | 6.815551 | 1.919078 |
| 1 | 6.812864 | 1.913814 |
| 1 | 6.787013 | 1.869232 |
| 1 | 6.801937 | 1.90309 |
| 1 | 6.787013 | 1.863323 |
| 1 | 6.758202 | 1.755875 |
| 1 | 6.785814 | 1.857332 |
| 1 | 6.753907 | 1.748188 |
| 1 | 6.781311 | 1.851258 |
| 1 | 6.752561 | 1.740363 |
| 1 | 6.776229 | 1.838849 |
| 1 | 6.735571 | 1.799341 |
| 1 | 6.751264 | 1.732394 |
| 1 | 6.710329 | 1.653213 |
| 1 | 6.732332 | 1.78533 |
| 1 | 6.708262 | 1.643453 |
| 1 | 6.728661 | 1.770852 |
| 1 | 6.696391 | 1.716003 |
| 1 | 6.696391 | 1.69897 |
| 1 | 6.567883 | 1.531479 |
| 1 | 6.564654 | 1.518514 |
| 1 | 6.560328 | 1.50515 |
| 1 | 6.560328 | 1.491362 |
| 1 | 6.549892 | 1.477121 |
| 1 | 6.384641 | 1.30103 |
| 2 | 7.488637 | 2.462398 |
| 2 | 7.488637 | 2.459393 |
| 2 | 7.490028 | 2.448706 |
| 2 | 7.490028 | 2.447158 |
| 2 | 7.490028 | 2.440909 |
| 2 | 7.489584 | 2.429752 |
| 2 | 7.488145 | 2.414973 |
| 2 | 7.488145 | 2.41162 |
| 2 | 7.48509 | 2.396199 |
| 2 | 7.483331 | 2.383815 |
| 2 | 7.483161 | 2.371068 |
| 2 | 7.480798 | 2.348305 |
| 2 | 7.406764 | 2.255272 |
| 2 | 7.406764 | 2.252853 |
| 2 | 7.291684 | 2.113943 |
| 2 | 7.290535 | 2.10721 |
| 2 | 7.285325 | 2.082785 |
| 2 | 7.284609 | 2.079181 |
| 2 | 7.218312 | 1.995635 |
| 2 | 7.212301 | 1.968483 |
| 2 | 7.208427 | 1.959041 |
| 2 | 7.14835 | 1.851258 |
| 2 | 7.146993 | 1.845098 |
| 2 | 7.137682 | 1.812913 |
| 2 | 7.093795 | 1.755875 |
| 2 | 6.901419 | 1.556303 |
| 2 | 6.896099 | 1.544068 |
| 2 | 6.889634 | 1.531479 |
| 2 | 6.765022 | 1.39794 |
| 2 | 6.750287 | 1.380211 |
| 3 | 6.328216 | 2.049218 |
| 3 | 6.328216 | 2.045323 |
| 3 | 6.328216 | 2.041393 |
| 3 | 6.33158 | 2.029384 |
| 3 | 6.336204 | 2.004321 |
| 3 | 6.341531 | 1.977724 |
| 3 | 6.341531 | 1.968483 |
| 3 | 6.341531 | 1.944483 |
| 3 | 6.345086 | 1.929419 |
| 3 | 6.345086 | 1.913814 |
| 3 | 6.345086 | 1.897627 |
| 3 | 6.334432 | 1.763428 |
| 3 | 6.334432 | 1.755875 |
| 3 | 6.334432 | 1.748188 |
| 3 | 6.326783 | 1.69897 |
| 3 | 6.326783 | 1.690196 |
| 3 | 6.304051 | 1.633469 |
| 3 | 6.296417 | 1.579784 |
| 3 | 6.257112 | 1.50515 |
| 3 | 6.189468 | 1.322219 |
| 3 | 6.180954 | 1.30103 |
| 4 | 8.205449 | 3.077004 |
| 4 | 8.205334 | 3.07664 |
| 4 | 8.20507 | 3.075182 |
| 4 | 8.204664 | 3.073718 |
| 4 | 8.204516 | 3.072985 |
| 4 | 6.935452 | 2.227887 |
| 4 | 8.204266 | 3.069668 |
| 4 | 8.204174 | 3.065953 |
| 4 | 8.198256 | 3.046885 |
| 4 | 8.196186 | 3.031409 |
| 4 | 6.932943 | 2.201397 |
| 4 | 8.180283 | 3.007748 |
| 4 | 8.133608 | 2.950851 |
| 4 | 8.133666 | 2.950365 |
| 4 | 8.133666 | 2.949878 |
| 4 | 6.561457 | 1.60206 |
| 4 | 6.555521 | 1.591065 |
| 4 | 6.55182 | 1.579784 |
| 4 | 6.548433 | 1.568202 |
| 4 | 6.548433 | 1.556303 |
| 4 | 6.548433 | 1.544068 |
| 4 | 6.546134 | 1.531479 |
| 4 | 6.546134 | 1.518514 |
| 4 | 6.546134 | 1.50515 |
| 4 | 6.542244 | 1.491362 |
| 4 | 6.537916 | 1.477121 |
| 4 | 6.533291 | 1.462398 |
| 4 | 6.527974 | 1.447158 |
| 4 | 6.521077 | 1.431364 |
| 4 | 6.512961 | 1.414973 |
| 4 | 6.504996 | 1.39794 |
| 4 | 6.495121 | 1.380211 |
| 4 | 6.484342 | 1.361728 |
| 4 | 6.461675 | 1.322219 |
| 4 | 6.932943 | 2.198657 |
| 4 | 7.188449 | 2.093422 |
| 4 | 8.12163 | 2.928908 |
| 4 | 6.932943 | 2.1959 |
| 4 | 6.873971 | 2.004321 |
| 4 | 6.872984 | 2 |
| 4 | 6.872984 | 1.995635 |
| 4 | 7.188449 | 2.082785 |
| 4 | 8.119134 | 2.916454 |
| 4 | 6.823647 | 1.869232 |
| 4 | 6.823647 | 1.863323 |
| 4 | 6.823647 | 1.857332 |
| 4 | 6.823647 | 1.851258 |
| 4 | 6.823647 | 1.845098 |
| 4 | 6.823647 | 1.838849 |
| 4 | 6.823647 | 1.832509 |
| 4 | 6.820189 | 1.78533 |
| 4 | 6.820189 | 1.778151 |
| 4 | 6.818833 | 1.770852 |
| 4 | 6.817286 | 1.763428 |
| 4 | 6.815536 | 1.755875 |
| 4 | 6.814351 | 1.748188 |
| 4 | 6.725016 | 1.60206 |
| 4 | 6.72117 | 1.591065 |
| 4 | 6.717243 | 1.579784 |
| 4 | 6.713598 | 1.568202 |
| 4 | 6.708353 | 1.556303 |
| 4 | 6.704825 | 1.544068 |
| 4 | 6.698305 | 1.531479 |
| 4 | 6.663859 | 1.491362 |
| 4 | 6.593511 | 1.414973 |
| 4 | 6.52342 | 1.342423 |
| 4 | 6.50499 | 1.322219 |
| 4 | 6.036647 | 1.740363 |
| 4 | 6.872984 | 1.991226 |
| 4 | 7.090433 | 1.838849 |
| 4 | 8.096313 | 2.873902 |
| 4 | 8.060622 | 2.822822 |
| 4 | 5.894747 | 1.518514 |
| 4 | 6.872984 | 1.986772 |
| 4 | 7.090433 | 1.832509 |
| 4 | 8.060504 | 2.817565 |
| 4 | 6.801479 | 1.623249 |
| 4 | 6.799003 | 1.612784 |
| 4 | 6.797771 | 1.60206 |
| 4 | 6.797771 | 1.591065 |
| 4 | 6.796392 | 1.579784 |
| 4 | 6.794524 | 1.568202 |
| 4 | 6.79258 | 1.556303 |
| 4 | 6.791305 | 1.544068 |
| 4 | 6.789477 | 1.531479 |
| 4 | 6.787705 | 1.518514 |
| 4 | 6.785541 | 1.50515 |
| 4 | 6.783881 | 1.491362 |
| 4 | 6.782106 | 1.477121 |
| 4 | 6.77935 | 1.462398 |
| 4 | 6.774052 | 1.447158 |
| 4 | 6.7672 | 1.431364 |
| 4 | 6.759046 | 1.414973 |
| 4 | 6.749273 | 1.39794 |
| 4 | 6.738902 | 1.380211 |
| 4 | 6.705361 | 1.342423 |
| 4 | 5.894747 | 1.50515 |
| 4 | 6.872984 | 1.982271 |
| 4 | 7.090433 | 1.826075 |
| 4 | 8.035583 | 2.782473 |
| 4 | 8.035442 | 2.780317 |
| 4 | 8.035182 | 2.775974 |
| 4 | 7.94505 | 2.694605 |
| 4 | 7.94505 | 2.693727 |
| 4 | 7.919998 | 2.640481 |
| 4 | 7.91981 | 2.639487 |
| 4 | 7.919558 | 2.63749 |
| 4 | 5.894747 | 1.491362 |
| 4 | 6.872984 | 1.977724 |
| 4 | 7.090433 | 1.819544 |
| 4 | 6.990751 | 1.90309 |
| 4 | 7.169816 | 1.826075 |
| 4 | 7.901167 | 2.608526 |
| 4 | 6.866411 | 1.568202 |
| 4 | 6.863744 | 1.556303 |
| 4 | 6.860339 | 1.544068 |
| 4 | 6.8561 | 1.531479 |
| 4 | 6.850943 | 1.518514 |
| 4 | 6.84597 | 1.50515 |
| 4 | 6.840015 | 1.491362 |
| 4 | 6.834002 | 1.477121 |
| 4 | 6.827169 | 1.462398 |
| 4 | 6.821152 | 1.447158 |
| 4 | 6.815055 | 1.431364 |
| 4 | 6.807693 | 1.414973 |
| 4 | 6.798083 | 1.39794 |
| 4 | 6.788435 | 1.380211 |
| 4 | 6.775578 | 1.361728 |
| 4 | 6.758379 | 1.342423 |
| 4 | 6.737421 | 1.322219 |
| 4 | 5.894747 | 1.477121 |
| 4 | 6.872984 | 1.973128 |
| 4 | 7.090433 | 1.812913 |
| 4 | 6.990751 | 1.897627 |
| 4 | 7.168882 | 1.819544 |
| 4 | 7.856704 | 2.557507 |
| 4 | 7.741778 | 2.432969 |
| 4 | 7.7408 | 2.429752 |
| 4 | 7.739935 | 2.426511 |
| 4 | 7.739164 | 2.423246 |
| 4 | 7.738338 | 2.419956 |
| 4 | 7.72338 | 2.382017 |
| 4 | 5.881769 | 1.462398 |
| 4 | 6.872984 | 1.968483 |
| 4 | 7.09106 | 1.80618 |
| 4 | 6.990751 | 1.892095 |
| 4 | 7.168012 | 1.812913 |
| 4 | 7.221757 | 1.94939 |
| 4 | 7.655478 | 2.292256 |
| 4 | 7.654485 | 2.287802 |
| 4 | 7.653401 | 2.283301 |
| 4 | 7.651942 | 2.278754 |
| 4 | 5.867424 | 1.431364 |
| 4 | 6.872984 | 1.963788 |
| 4 | 7.09106 | 1.799341 |
| 4 | 6.57514 | 1.447158 |
| 4 | 7.166559 | 1.80618 |
| 4 | 7.220612 | 1.944483 |
| 4 | 7.217782 | 1.934498 |
| 4 | 7.21549 | 1.924279 |
| 4 | 7.161956 | 1.845098 |
| 4 | 7.64925 | 2.269513 |
| 4 | 7.630433 | 2.243038 |
| 4 | 7.560054 | 2.164353 |
| 4 | 5.829206 | 1.39794 |
| 4 | 6.872984 | 1.959041 |
| 4 | 7.09106 | 1.792392 |
| 4 | 6.570402 | 1.431364 |
| 4 | 7.165751 | 1.799341 |
| 4 | 7.159267 | 1.826075 |
| 4 | 7.517043 | 2.100371 |
| 4 | 7.515921 | 2.09691 |
| 4 | 6.871532 | 1.94939 |
| 4 | 7.089574 | 1.78533 |
| 4 | 6.565628 | 1.414973 |
| 4 | 7.16466 | 1.792392 |
| 4 | 7.15836 | 1.819544 |
| 4 | 7.459701 | 2.017033 |
| 4 | 7.421119 | 1.973128 |
| 4 | 7.411725 | 1.959041 |
| 4 | 6.789493 | 1.851258 |
| 4 | 7.087931 | 1.778151 |
| 4 | 6.557573 | 1.39794 |
| 4 | 7.160412 | 1.778151 |
| 4 | 7.146353 | 1.778151 |
| 4 | 7.340607 | 1.875061 |
| 4 | 7.257214 | 1.792392 |
| 4 | 7.194228 | 1.732394 |
| 4 | 7.060445 | 1.60206 |
| 4 | 7.049411 | 1.591065 |
| 4 | 6.86208 | 1.39794 |
| 4 | 6.839869 | 1.380211 |
| 4 | 6.785683 | 1.832509 |
| 4 | 7.086139 | 1.770852 |
| 4 | 6.54718 | 1.380211 |
| 4 | 7.157061 | 1.763428 |
| 4 | 7.144859 | 1.770852 |
| 4 | 6.771702 | 1.812913 |
| 4 | 7.084482 | 1.763428 |
| 4 | 6.537161 | 1.361728 |
| 4 | 7.154208 | 1.748188 |
| 4 | 7.134589 | 1.690196 |
| 4 | 7.143139 | 1.763428 |
| 4 | 6.730468 | 1.724276 |
| 4 | 7.082101 | 1.755875 |
| 4 | 6.526967 | 1.342423 |
| 4 | 7.133277 | 1.681241 |
| 4 | 7.121487 | 1.716003 |
| 4 | 6.717027 | 1.690196 |
| 4 | 7.080468 | 1.748188 |
| 4 | 6.517863 | 1.322219 |
| 4 | 7.131428 | 1.672098 |
| 4 | 7.113277 | 1.69897 |
| 4 | 7.048329 | 1.633469 |
| 4 | 6.937863 | 1.518514 |
| 4 | 6.795511 | 1.380211 |
| 4 | 6.713907 | 1.681241 |
| 4 | 7.078338 | 1.740363 |
| 4 | 6.51162 | 1.30103 |
| 4 | 7.129128 | 1.662758 |
| 4 | 6.771376 | 1.342423 |
| 4 | 6.710126 | 1.672098 |
| 4 | 7.076798 | 1.732394 |
| 4 | 7.089213 | 1.591065 |
| 4 | 6.64042 | 1.491362 |
| 4 | 7.075485 | 1.724276 |
| 4 | 7.084291 | 1.579784 |
| 4 | 6.638302 | 1.477121 |
| 4 | 7.072529 | 1.716003 |
| 4 | 7.079221 | 1.568202 |
| 4 | 6.634731 | 1.462398 |
| 4 | 7.070577 | 1.70757 |
| 4 | 7.074643 | 1.556303 |
| 4 | 6.630823 | 1.447158 |
| 4 | 7.068465 | 1.69897 |
| 4 | 7.069058 | 1.544068 |
| 4 | 7.066777 | 1.690196 |
| 4 | 7.059217 | 1.531479 |
| 4 | 7.060505 | 1.672098 |
| 4 | 6.967258 | 1.431364 |
| 4 | 6.858575 | 1.322219 |
| 4 | 7.037383 | 1.623249 |
| 4 | 6.951287 | 1.531479 |
| 4 | 6.909385 | 1.477121 |
| 4 | 6.869723 | 1.431364 |
| 4 | 6.758827 | 1.30103 |
| 5 | 7.020563 | 2.217484 |
| 5 | 7.019236 | 2.214844 |
| 5 | 7.015759 | 2.190332 |
| 5 | 7.014673 | 2.187521 |
| 5 | 6.990801 | 2.143015 |
| 5 | 6.5189 | 1.880814 |
| 5 | 6.486913 | 1.748188 |
| 5 | 6.475608 | 1.672098 |
| 5 | 6.475608 | 1.662758 |
| 5 | 6.454237 | 1.50515 |
| 5 | 6.454237 | 1.491362 |
| 5 | 6.44987 | 1.477121 |
| 5 | 6.445545 | 1.462398 |
| 5 | 6.448015 | 1.447158 |
| 5 | 6.451007 | 1.431364 |
| 5 | 6.451007 | 1.414973 |
| 5 | 6.451007 | 1.39794 |
| 5 | 6.451007 | 1.380211 |
| 5 | 6.451007 | 1.361728 |
| 5 | 6.451007 | 1.342423 |
| 5 | 6.44783 | 1.322219 |
| 5 | 6.44783 | 1.30103 |
| 6 | 7.046813 | 2.376577 |
| 6 | 7.043986 | 2.356026 |
| 6 | 7.043184 | 2.342423 |
| 6 | 7.042725 | 2.32838 |
| 6 | 7.042725 | 2.324282 |
| 6 | 6.999923 | 2.281033 |
| 6 | 6.999154 | 2.262451 |
| 6 | 7.001749 | 2.238046 |
| 6 | 7.003549 | 2.230449 |
| 6 | 6.968538 | 2.198657 |
| 6 | 6.903515 | 2.146128 |
| 6 | 6.899526 | 2.130334 |
| 6 | 6.8355 | 2.068186 |
| 6 | 6.831475 | 2.053078 |
| 6 | 6.833857 | 2.037426 |
| 6 | 6.833346 | 2.0086 |
| 6 | 6.773952 | 1.939519 |
| 6 | 6.716992 | 1.869232 |
| 6 | 6.716992 | 1.851258 |
| 6 | 6.606367 | 1.770852 |
| 6 | 6.597109 | 1.748188 |
| 6 | 6.561687 | 1.690196 |
| 6 | 6.37202 | 1.531479 |
| 7 | 7.280698 | 2.562293 |
| 7 | 7.280698 | 2.555094 |
| 7 | 7.281369 | 2.553883 |
| 7 | 7.281782 | 2.539076 |
| 7 | 7.282414 | 2.534026 |
| 7 | 7.282536 | 2.518514 |
| 7 | 7.203922 | 2.437751 |
| 7 | 7.200971 | 2.418301 |
| 7 | 7.201777 | 2.41162 |
| 7 | 7.202217 | 2.394452 |
| 7 | 7.193347 | 2.367356 |
| 7 | 6.501535 | 1.724276 |
| 7 | 6.513955 | 1.544068 |
| 7 | 6.501535 | 1.716003 |
| 7 | 6.51613 | 1.531479 |
| 7 | 6.603148 | 1.845098 |
| 7 | 6.600962 | 1.838849 |
| 7 | 6.600962 | 1.832509 |
| 7 | 6.501535 | 1.70757 |
| 7 | 6.519574 | 1.518514 |
| 7 | 6.600962 | 1.826075 |
| 7 | 6.39799 | 1.531479 |
| 7 | 6.519574 | 1.50515 |
| 7 | 6.600962 | 1.819544 |
| 7 | 6.39353 | 1.518514 |
| 7 | 6.519574 | 1.491362 |
| 7 | 6.596313 | 1.812913 |
| 7 | 6.571371 | 1.778151 |
| 7 | 6.56466 | 1.770852 |
| 7 | 6.543139 | 1.740363 |
| 7 | 6.390595 | 1.50515 |
| 7 | 6.519574 | 1.477121 |
| 7 | 6.513588 | 1.681241 |
| 7 | 6.50309 | 1.653213 |
| 7 | 6.254679 | 1.477121 |
| 7 | 6.237255 | 1.447158 |
| 7 | 6.390595 | 1.491362 |
| 7 | 6.519574 | 1.462398 |
| 7 | 6.21441 | 1.380211 |
| 7 | 6.183514 | 1.322219 |
| 7 | 6.390595 | 1.477121 |
| 7 | 6.519574 | 1.447158 |
| 7 | 6.390595 | 1.462398 |
| 7 | 6.519574 | 1.431364 |
| 7 | 6.378858 | 1.431364 |
| 7 | 6.515181 | 1.414973 |
| 7 | 6.510731 | 1.39794 |
| 7 | 6.503214 | 1.380211 |
| 7 | 6.492614 | 1.361728 |
| 7 | 6.478776 | 1.342423 |

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sample_n`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(number) %>%
   sample_n(1)
```